# Drupal AJAX forms & commands

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I have a form updating with AJAX on select element change. Easy so far. The problem is that I need to return the form & also an ajax command at the same time.

If I need the form, I just return the `$form` array and if I need to return an ajax command I use `return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);`. Both works just fine.

The problem is that I don't get it how to combine both of them in the same return object.

Any ideas how can I do that?

Comment: Check "Ajax Comments" contributed module you will get all the information there.

Comment: it's not what I need. in ajax comments they return the whole rendered form. I need to return just part of an existing form...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a backup solution, I'll do it this way:

```
$form['#suffix'] = '<script type="text/javascript">some_function_to_do_what_i_need();</script>';
return $form;
```

this should work.

Comment: did you find a better solution eventually?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use `$form['#attached']['js'][] = drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module') . '/js/functionality.js'; return $form;`?

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass to `drupal_render()` the form array, then add it to your `$commands` as an AJAX command. You should use code similar to the following one.

```
function my_ajax_form_callback($form, &$form_state) {
  $new_state = array();
  $new_state['build_info'] = $form_state['build_info'];
  $new_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
  $new_state['values'] = array();
  $new_state += form_state_defaults();

  $new_form_array = drupal_rebuild_form('my_ajax_form_id', $new_state);
  $new_form = drupal_render($new_form_array);

  $commands = array();
  $commands[] = ajax_command_html('#form-container-element-id', $new_form);

  return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
}
```

Comment: I need to return just part of the form, not the whole rebuild, rendered form.

Comment: Then render the form element and pass it as an ajax command. Same principle I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `hook_ajax_render_alter(&$commands)` e.g.

```
function myModule_ajax_render_alter(&$commands) {
  $commands[] = myModule_custom_command('hi');
}
```

See the [documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_ajax_render_alter/7) for details.